# Vuetify - How to validate array of inputs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-validator

I've a following field in the form, and user can create/add another field for the address. How can I validate all fields with **name=address**

```
<v-col cols="12">
    <v-text-field v-for="(item, index) in address" :key="index"
        :value=item.value
        name=address[]
        prepend-icon="home_office"
        placeholder="Address"
    ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

The script part:

```
<script>

export default {
    name: "Contact",
    data: () => ({
        dialog: false,
        valid: false,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        nameRules: [
            v => !!v || 'Name is required',
            v => v.length >= 3 || 'Name must be more than 3 characters',
            v => v.length <= 255 || 'Name must be less than 255 characters',
        ],
        address: [
            {
                value: ''
            },
            {
                value: 'Test2'
            }
        ]
    }),
    methods: {
        create(){
            this.$store.dispatch('createContact')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
        },
        submit () {
            console.log(this.$refs.form.validate());

            // this.$refs.form.validate()
        },
        clear () {
            this.$refs.form.reset()
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you at least one field should be valide or all fields?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim all fields that are filled.

Comment: something like https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/ExYRrdy?editors=1010?

Comment: From what I can see it is automatically working for each field. No need to do something with forEach, or some other array function. That is nice. 
One more question - do you maybe know how to get the name of the input field in the rules (to pass it to the message)?

Comment: i'm searching how to do that